# Is it okay to add new attributes to svg elements as markers?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

Is it okay to create an svg element and then add an arbitrary attribute to it?

```
var myelt = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "line");
var myelt.my_name = "this is a marker I'm attaching to the element, ok?";
```

It seems like this works in Chrome, but is it really an acceptable thing to do in general, for all browsers?

Comment: as long as your attribute doesn't conflict with another application or specification, you're fine

Comment: The XML way is to create a custom namespace and store stuff in that. The html way is data- attributes. Data attributes might be coming to SVG in html at some point depending on how the SVG 2 specification pans out.